# Nested query in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

In Ms Access i can create a query, called "CustomerList" with following datas:

```
CustomerName, City, Revenue
```

Then i can create another query, for instance "CustomerCount" like:

```
Select count(*) as Tot
from CustomerList   ( <<<- is a query name)
where CustomerList.City
```

This query is based on another Query. Is it possible to do the same in MYSQL ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, like this

```
Select count(*) as Tot
from
(
  select City from some_table
) x
where x.City = 'NYC'
```

You have to alias subqueries.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a `VIEW`

A `VIEW` works like a table but really is a select on one or more tables.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a column or an alias named `City` in the nested query
You can only do this::

```
Select count(*) as Tot
from 
/*
select City,..... your query



*/

CustomerList   where CustomerList.City
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a subquery.

```
select count(*) as Tot

from ( 
  select City from some_table
) c

where c.City = 'YOURCITY'
```

`c` in this case, is an alias of the the subquery.